# Recommendation for green laser pointer for 6" Orion SkyQuest; one integrated with finder or a separate laser added to current configuration?

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, amateur-observing

I would like to replace the default finder scope on my 6" Orion SkyQuest with one that incorporates a green laser.

Do such things exist, and if so, what should I look for in the laser specifications?

Would it be better to simply mount a laser pointer to my existing finder or the telescope?

Comment: It can be a finder scope with *integrated* green laser, or JUST a green laser that we attach to the scope using bungee cords and clips. 

I want the laser to be clearly visible, but I just don't want a laser that is dangerous since a lot of kids will be around.

Comment: I've adjusted the wording of your question to avoid "shopping question" close votes. Stack Exchange questions should be answerable with fact-based answers that can be potentially correct.

Comment: I mounted my green laser pointer in a small finder mount.  Now I can put it on several different telescopes

Comment: @DavidZimmerman how did you mount it and how do you then align the laser to the other two? This sounds like an excellent answer to the question!

Answer (score 3):

I hesitate to post this as an answer because it doesn't directly answer your question, but it does answer your overall problem.

***Do not rely on a laser as a finder***.  Any dark site will have rules against using them, as they will interfere with other's use of the site.  It will affect yours and other's night vision.  Ruin photos of people imaging anywhere you point it.

Using one in your own light polluted back yard may seem ok.  But eventually you're going to want to go to a dark site, and you'll need an appropriate finder.  If all you ever used before your visit is a laser, you're going to waste your time at the dark site learning or fiddling with something new.

Invest in a good finder, and get adept at using it.  I use a Telrad on pretty much avery scope I own.  You should ask for recommendations from other too, but don't prefix the question by saying it has to be a laser.

Lasers are fine tools at public events used as pointers (in the hands of resposible opperators).  But that' pretty much it.

Comment: I have to agree with this. Also they can be dangerous to pilots of planes flying overhead. The advice to "Invest in a good finder, and get adept at using it" is good. On my Dobsonian I go from Telrad to finder to eyepiece. On my refractor I go from Baader Sky-Surfer to eyepiece.